# Lasso coefficient plot looks "strange"

Tags: r, machine-learning, lasso

[image]

I'm fitting a Lasso model with generated data, but the plot of extracted coefficients fitted against log lambda doesn't seem correct.  Is there something wrong with my code, or are plots like this quite common for lasso? TIA!

```
x<-rnorm(100)
e<-0.1*rnorm(100)
y <- 1 + -0.1*x + 0.05*x^2 + 0.75*x^3 + e
grid=10^seq(4,-2, length =100)
x<-model.matrix(y~poly(x, 8, raw = T), data=dat)[,-1]
lasso_reg<-glmnet(x, y, alpha=1,lambda=grid)
plot(lasso_reg, xvar="lambda")
```

Comment: It's highly unusual to fit an eighth-degree polynomial to a dataset with cubic behavior.  One would expect at most four coefficients to persist very long as $\lambda$ is increased.

Comment: What do you think is strange about this? This just looks like a lasso plot to me.